# Firebase keeps redirecting example.com/username to example.com/#/

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I am trying to extract the username from the current URL example.com/username but firebase keeps directing it to example.com/#/ due to which username changes dynamically.

The website is built on flutter

firebase.json file:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "dynamicLinks": true,
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Visuals:

[image: Visuals of redirection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the `rewrites` node in your `firebase.json`:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/**",
    "dynamicLinks": true,
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

This tells Firebase Hosting to rewrite any incoming path (`"source": "/**"`) to the same `index.html` file (`"destination": "/index.html"`).

If you don't want it to perform this rewrite, you should remove it from the `firebase.json` configuration file.

Comment: Hi @Frank, I tried it but then it shows page not found

Comment: So... does the page exist then? Note that I have a feeling we're looking at a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, and it would probably be easier to help if you show a [minimal, but complete/standalone repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am trying to build a web page where you can view user profile through link example.com/username and yes https://noobappuat.web.app does exist but noob.web.app/username shows page doesn't exist.

I have explained it further in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221464/how-to-create-a-variable-username-and-insert-it-in-website-url-like-noob-com

Comment: It's not an explanation that is lacking, but the corresponding code that reproduces the problem. If you click on a link to a page, that page has to exist or otherwise you'll get a 404. If you expect some other behavior, you likely have a reason for that, but we can't see that in your question.